# how can we transform entire web.config from staging slot to production slot in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment, azure-deployment-slots

I have created multiple slots(test, stage and prod) in my azure app service. Similarly I have created respective web.config files for each environment. I am deploying my application through octopus deployment tool in test environment slot, so initially it's picking web.test.config file and it's working fine.

But, I want to swap complete transformation section of web.config file when I swap it to stage or Prod slot while doing swapping through azure portal. Is there any way to do ?

using application setting and connection string of configuration setting, I am able to segregate the setting of each slot. But I am not sure how can I do it for other section like system.identityModel,system.web system.identityModel.services, etc. Therefore I want to replace complete transformation section according to environment while doing swapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I talked with the app service team, they said slots are not meant for this purpose. The main purpose of slots is to allow deployment of new versions with little or no downtime. Or to test new features with a small percentage of the traffic. Not really for different environments, you should use have separate app services for that, to which you deploy separately.